# Why do depictions of foreigners in English media compulsively insert foreign words from their mother tongue?

Tags: history, literary-techniques, non-native-english, mass-media

There is something that has been bugging me about depiction of foreigners in various English media (that doesn't occur, say, in Polish media).

The "foreigner" characters keep replacing *common English words they clearly know* with common words from their mother tongue *in regular, relaxed, every day situations*.
As far as I'm aware, this is **unlike real people speaking a secondary language**, who use words from their mother tongue when they're fishing for a word they don't know or can't remember, or are reflexively cursing. (Or, like Bitter dreggs pointed out, are under stress.)

For example:

- I recall seeing several times, in different TV series or movies, a Mexican-maid-working-in-USA that constantly replaces "yes" with "si" and "sir" with "senior".
- In Brandon Sanderson's novel *Elantris*, a secondary character that is a foreigner relative to the rest of the cast, keeps using words for "friend" and "understand" in in-fiction language.
- In video game *CrossCode*, a promiment French character keeps using French phrases that are *definitely not* common loan phrases in English, and also replaces "my" with "mon".
- And there several more examples that I can never clearly recall when I'm talking about this.

Is this a lazy writing technique that got popularised by some specific work of fiction? Is there some historical precedent where a group of immigrants to England/USA **did** speak exactly like that?

Comment: I had a real trouble deciding whether to post this here or to Writing, and I didn't have enough specific examples to post it to Movies, Literature, or Gaming.

Comment: Theere's even a slight cross-over with [psychology.se] or [linguistics.se], as it's a well known phenomenon that people under stress will react using the language with the greatest emotional connection - usually their first language, or swear words. I'll leave it to others to advise you on what site this sits best.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs.Except, as I tried to **clearly state in the question**, that is a regular thing that happens in real world. I'm not asking about that. I'll edit in "under stress" to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think this is going to be hard to answer definitively. I have a suggestion for at least some cases but without asking the authors in question I'm not sure it's a real answer: foreign words are used to remind the reader of the foreign nature of the character, but very common (or similar to English) foreign words are used so as not to interrupt the flow of reading

Comment: @ChrisH Good points all around. Still, it comes off a bit like trying to remind your audience that a character is a professional chef by constantly having them make cooking-related puns, or by wearing an apron and that tall white hat (toque?) 24/7. :P

Comment: @ChrisH And, of course, fictional works use conventions that do not match real life 1:1. For instance, people rarely speak as fluently and concisely as they do in any given play/movie/series/book/game; however, that is a near-universal convention as I can tell.

Comment: Another example is Agatha Christie's Hercule Poirot, a Belgian private detective resident in England, who uses phrases like  _mon ami_. I don't suppose she originated the idea; it's just a cliché of light fiction.

Comment: The practice alluded to in the question is a [trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoirotSpeak), is it not?

Comment: @Kate, it is actually called 'Poirot Speak' on TV Tropes, and I see there that _The Da Vinci Code_ is full of it (but we knew that).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for finding TV Tropes link, but the description also includes messing up syntax and mistranslating idioms, which *are* things that I've seen real people do.

Comment: @KateBunting I think **you might be onto something**. While I haven't read the books, I've seen mentioned several times that this was deliberate and justified in-fiction in that Poirot was trying to appear as a non-threatening "funny foreigner". And Agatha Christie *was* an extremely popular author. The question is - did she introduce/popularis this trope, or merely played with it when it had already been popular?

Comment: The trope was around long before Agatha Christie. As the TV Tropes page points out in its 'Literature' section, another example is Professor Van Helsing in Bram Stoker's _Dracula_ (1897).

Comment: There is a real phenomenon that this is related to: [code-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching). This is mostly described in the context of conversations between bilinguals. but certainly occurs in other circumstances too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is something that has been bugging me about depiction of foreigners in various English media (that doesn't occur, say, in Polish media).
>
> The "foreigner" characters keep replacing common English words they clearly know with common words from their mother tongue in regular, relaxed, every day situations.

This is relatively easily explained: English literary tradition (and real life) does the converse: It has English speaking characters (and real people) mangling foreign languages by inserting at random the few words of a foreign language that they know:

[To a Frenchman]: "Understandez-vous que je means?" (Do you understand what I mean?)

[To a German]: "Guten Morgen, sell you the cigarettes?"

[To the Spaniard]: "Two cervezas please"

in which the archetypal Englishman will insert foreign words in order to help the foreigner.

This is done on the basis of the accepted truth in the native English-speaking world that **"All foreigners speak English, they just pretend that they don't to annoy us."**

Thus *the "foreigner" characters keep replacing common English words they clearly know with common words from their mother tongue* because that is what English speaking people do when addressing foreigners.

Comment: Huh. I haven't really given enough thought to *"it's a projection"*. I'll wait for more answers - as is tradition - but yours seems pretty likely to be correct here.